# Form data is not sent on the page Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to send data to a third-party api, I have 2 forms on my page 1) On the header of the site, called by clicking on the button in the form of a pop-up, it works and sends data through the api. 2) the form is on the page, and no data is sent through it. what could be the problem? I attach the code of the post request

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#bot").on("submit", function() {
            let service = $("#service-ap").val();
            let email = $("#email-ap").val();
            let details = $("#details-ap").val();
            let formData = {
                "user": {
                    "service": service,
                    "email": email,
                    "details": details,
                }
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'there an endpoint here',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                ContentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#formData').html(data);
                },
                error: function(rest) {
                    console.log(rest);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the form

```
<form action="/#wpcf7-f5279-o5" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate" data-status="init" id="bot" data-hs-cf-bound="true">
</div>
<div class="section-form__caption">Form</div>

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap services"><select name="services" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required ui-select" id="service-ap" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Service*" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Service*</option><option value="service1">service1</option><option value="service2">service2</option><option value="service3">service3</option><option value="service4">service4</option></select></span>

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email ui-input" id="email-ap" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your email*"></span>

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap details"><textarea name="details" cols="40" rows="3" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required ui-input" id="details-ap" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Details*"></textarea></span>

<div class="request-form__button">
    <input type="submit" value="Send request" class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit ui-button"><span class="wpcf7-spinner"></span>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use `wpcf7_before_send_mail` and PHP rather than trying to use JS for this solution.  Much easier and more efficient.